# función no definida en una JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estoy realizando un drop down en cascada en un proyecto asp net core, lo raro es que ya realice dos select y me funcionan bien pero a la hora de ingresar un tercero me esta dando el error de que no esta definida.

Este es mi script:

```
<script src="~/js/dropdowncascada.js"></script>
<script>


        const urlObtenerSubCategorias = '@Url.Action("ObtenerSubCategorias", "Ticket")';
        const urlObtenerModulos = '@Url.Action("ObtenerModulos", "Ticket")';
        const urlObtenerMovimientos = '@Url.Action("ObtenerMovimientos", "Ticket")';

        $(function(){
            inicializarDropdownSubCategoria(urlObtenerSubCategorias);
            inicializarDropdownModulo(urlObtenerModulos);
            inicializarDropdownMovimiento(urlObtenerMovimientos);
        })

    });
</script>
```

En mi archivo dropdowncascada.js tengo las funciones:

```
function inicializarDropdownMovimiento(urlObtenerMovimientos) {
$("#IdModulo").change(async function () {
    const valorSeleccionado = $(this).val();

    const respuesta = await fetch(urlObtenerMovimientos, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: valorSeleccionado,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    });

    const json = await respuesta.json();
    const opciones = json.map(movimiento => `<option value=${movimiento.value}>${movimiento.text}</option>`);
    $("#IdMovimiento").html(opciones);
})
}
```

En esa misma tengo las otras dos que me funcionan bien[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero me puedan apoyar y decirme cual es mi error, que no entiendo por que me lo da.

Comment: "el error de que no esta definida." Edita la pregunta y escribe exactamente el error que te da. Además recarga la página borrando el caché, la recarga activa de visual studio no siempre aplica a js, dependiendo de tu configuración.